# How to retrieve LINQ object along with all its related info?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, linq-to-sql

Here is a sample schema where "=>" represent "one-to-many" relationship:
Contract => ContractCustomers
Contract => ContractDiscounts
Customers => ContractCustomers
DiscountType => ContractDiscounts
I am trying to retrieve the contract object along with all its related details using one call to the server.
So far I used LoadWith:

```
 using (Data.ABWXDataContext db = new Data.ABWXDataContext())
            {
                DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
                options.LoadWith<Data.Contract>(c => c.ContractCustomers);
                options.LoadWith<Data.Contract>(c => c.ContractDiscounts);
                options.LoadWith<Data.ContractDiscount>(c => c.DiscountType);
                options.LoadWith<Data.ContractCustomer>(c => c.Customers);
                db.LoadOptions = options;
                var Contract = from con in db.Contracts
                               where con.ContractId == contractId
                               select con;
                return Contract.ToList();
            }
        }
```

The above code works fine to include ContractDiscounts and ContractCustomers table. However it does not give me access to  (Discount Type, Customers). I understand that they are not children of contract, how can I accompany them with the contract object?

I apologize if this is a simple common task.

Comment: I'd go for `var Contract = db.Contracts.Where(c => c.ContractId == contractId;` and leave the method returning `IQueryable` but I don't think that would solve your problem. Can you post your metadata definitions for the classes.

Comment: I know, I'm not helping you much but I'm also a bit lost when it comes to more complex queries but it seems that using `JOIN` would possibly make it work. Not sure for the syntax though, have you tried including `JOIN` in your query?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268(v=vs.110).aspx#remarksToggle seems it can't be done. However it is possible with Entity Framework. Consider using that instead, given that it has active development.

Answer (score 0):

You can add load options not starting at `Contract`:

```
options.LoadWith<Data.ContractCustomer>(c => c.Customer);
options.LoadWith<Data.ContractDiscount>(c => c.Discount);
```

Note that adding many load options can cause multiple queries to be fired (1 + n problem). You'll have to check whether it's still efficient. It may be more efficient to query related data on demand later.

Answer (score 0):

[I found the answer on this question to work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3107530/2917579)

Copied answer:

I found out what it was! Linq to SQL will put the [DataMember()] attribute on the Child Records, But NOT the Parents. I had to add the [DataMember()] attribute under the association .

The Down Side is this is a Manual Entry to the context.designer.cs which will get overwritten if the dbml is changed :-(

```
[Association(Name="CustomerStatus_Customer", Storage="_CustomerStatus", ThisKey="CustomerStatusId", OtherKey="CustomerStatusId", IsForeignKey=true)]
[DataMember()]
public CustomerStatus CustomerStatus
{
    get
    {
        return this._CustomerStatus.Entity;
    }
    set
    { 
      ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not creating any side effects? (For instance, circular references, or eager loading when you _don't_ want it.) Manually changing the dbml is a big concern. Did you try what I suggested?